# Add button on a form other than records in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way to add a button on saved search results or list of records, like we can on opened record. For example, I wanted to add a button in the saved search results so i can customize the export to excel to minimize process after export.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is No; pages like Search Results and Record Lists are not scriptable.

You would have to make your own Suitelet page that mimics the page you're interested in. You would be able to add any buttons you want then.